# count the number of subarray in binary array in which number of zero is more than one

Tags: algorithm, sub-array

Given an binary array . find the number of  sub array in which number of zero is more than one?

I have managed to work out a naive O(N2) solution, is it possible to get better?

Comment: Show what you've got now.

Comment: Please show what you have already found. What do you mean by "number of sub array"? An example of a small input might make your question more clear.

Comment: Do you mean "number of zero is more than 1" or "number of zero is more than the number of one"?

Answer (score 1):

You call F[i] is the number of bit 1 from a[1] to a[i]; G[i] is the number of bit 0 from a[1] to a[i]. So we have to find the number of pair i,j (0<=i<j<=n) that: **F[j]-F[i]< G[j]- G[i].**

It can take O(N^2), but if we transform that expression:

F[j] - F[i]< G[j] - G[i]

<=> F[j] - G[j] < F[i] - G[i] (*)

If we call **C[i] = F[i]- G[i]**, so:

(*) <=> C[j] < C[i].

The problem will change to that: find the number of pair (i, j) that **i < j** and **C[i] > C[j]**. We can easily solve with Binary Search Tree in approximately **O(NlogN)**